How to create a user with installation privileges without granting full administrator privileges?
I'm Jhoan, new to this forum and new to the world of systems administration. My company is small, and we're looking for a solution to manage our clients' computers more efficiently.
We have remote access to our clients' PCs and a platform to run PowerShell scripts on them. We need to create a local user on each PC, without administrator privileges, which we'll call a "standard user." This user should be able to install, update, and uninstall software, but only when our designated "approver" (who has access to administrator credentials) authorizes it, by providing either their own credentials or those of a local administrator.
This would allow us to reduce support calls related to software installation. I've tried using local group policies, but haven't found an effective solution.
Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how we could achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried using local group policies to allow standard users to install software, but I haven't found any settings that allow this in a secure and controlled way.
